# Python os.system returns 103

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a py script (let say sub-script) within a main-script via

```
os.system('script_customer_update')
```

When I'm call the main script it runs through without any exception and the sub-script wasn't performed.

When I'm call the Python Shell and put in the following in

```
import os
os.system('script_customer_update')
```

I'm receiving a returncode 103

When I open the sub-script direct and run it via F5, it runs through without any exceptions.

Any idea what is wrong?
Python 3 is installed.

Comment: it's not a Python error, your script is returning '103' try `out = subprocess.check_output('script_customer_update', shell=True)` then `print(out)`, of course, you need to `import subprocess`

Comment: If both main and sub scripts are written in *Python*, why going through `os.system`? Why not simply import the subscript in the mainscript and run its entrypoint?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That will also give me the following information:
File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'script_customer_update.py' returned non-zero exit status 103.